# Future Perfect with 2 events

Tags: future-perfect

I've been working through some future tenses exercises and I'm wondering about which of the following alternatives is correct:

> 1. By the time I'm 30, I **will have got married** and **will have moved out** to the countryside.
> 2. By the time I'm 30, I **will have got married** and **moved out** to the countryside.

So my question is whether repeating *will have* twice in the first alternative is redundant or not? Would it be enough (and still correct) to simply use the second alternative?

Comment: We would be more likely to say *will have gotten* in America.

Comment: You needn't repeat *will have*. It's your choice.  Yes, this would be BrE as its get, got, got.